# Installing Plesk on already running and used VPS

Tags: vps, plesk, reinstall

I want to install PLESK on our VPS. We are already using this VPS is in production and the hosting company recommend to reinstall the server first, then install Plesk and then republish the data. 
However, I can find no information anywhere if it is risky to install Plesk on an already running productive VPS without reinstalling it before. 
The problem is: A former coder has produced code that we use on daily basis, and I don't know if he made any changes on the server, which would have gone when performing the prior reinstall.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

An official [Software Requirements document for Plesk in Windows](https://docs.plesk.com/release-notes/12.5/software-requirements/), tells that "**We strongly recommend that you install Plesk for Microsoft Windows on a clean server**".

[image]

It has a valid reason, because when you install a Plesk panel, the components required to build the Windows Hosting environment is installed by Plesk itself. It's installation wizard provides you with the component/roles/software/server selection to install your choice of software in Windows system.

That means, it won't recognize none of your pre-installed components, and you won't be able to manage them from Plesk. Hence, it's not recommended to install Plesk in a production VPS as it may also corrupt the functionality of existing environment.

If control panel is your only concern, I would recommend you [SolidCP](https://solidcp.com/). It's a free control panel built for Windows VPS. The best thing is, you can install it on your production setup without interrupting its functionality. It'll easily recognize the installed components/roles/servers allowing you to integrate them with SolidCP.

Installation part is straightforward - once installed you just have to integrate the existing server components in SolidCP and then you could easily manage them from SolidCP. It also allows you to import your existing databases, websites, domains, etc. from SolidCP to manage them.

Comment: Thank you a thousand times for your detailed answer - Stupid me forgot to mention that I am on a OpenSuse Linux server. Do you know something like SolidCP also for this environment?

Comment: Oh my bad ... I should have asked about your existing setup. Well, I don't think any Linux based control panel could be installed on existing/production server.

Comment: Definitely correct. upvoted. However so far the only conflicts I can surmise are A.) Folder permissions (IUSER iis), B.) mysql port C.) Default website in IIS is taken control of completely (it will alter bindings), and D.) obviously nothing is imported. So you can infact install plesk on a running system, I have done just that. Knowing that if it's production, there will be downtime during configuration and mysql replacement.